# Waiting for the content of .then in promise to end before returning

Tags: bluebird, bookshelf.js

Why is my first .then not holding onto the promise since it isn't returning anything ?
In the following function, the console reads: 
blablabla
... list of ids

implying that the second .then got executed before the first one did.

```
    Model.collection().query(...).fetch().then(function(result) {
        // result is a list of models.
        // I want to run a promise on each of these models in order to add stuff to them
        result.each(function(model) {
            New promise based task on model with .then(function(r) {
                console.log(model.id);
                // with something like:
                model.set('newvalue', r.value);
            });
        });
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log('blablabla');
        return res.json(result.toJSON());
    }).catch(next);
};
```

Comment: `each` does not support async operations. You need to use some sort of async iterator and return that inside your first then handler

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Bookshelf's collection.mapThen, like this:

```js
SomeModel.collection().fetch()
.then(function(collection) {
    // collection is a bookshelf collection object
    // collection.mapThen returns a promise
    return collection.mapThen(function(model) {
        console.log("model " + model.id);
        // we can return another promise inside here, and the .mapThen promise 
        // won't be resolved until this one is.
        return knex('users').where({id: model.get('user_id')}).first()
        .then(function(u) {
            model.set('userName', u.user_name);
            // return model as the result of the map.
            return model;
        });
    })
})
.then(function(results) {
    // results is a list of all the modified models
    console.log('blablabla');
    return res.json(results);
})
.catch(next);
```

Comment: Actually, for some reason this does not work, but using the map method and the sequence of returns did ...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
Do you know if there is a way of achieving this via the relations ?

Comment: To clarify: i did this:
    var subResults = resp.map(function(model) {
        return app.db.knex(model.get('model')).select().where('id', model.get('foreign_id')).then(function(result) {
            model.set('resource', result);
            return model;
        });             
    });
    return require('bluebird').all(subResults).thenReturn(resp);

Comment: If it's a relationship managed by bookshelf, would [collection.load('other')](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-load) work for you?